# How do I test model level triggers on appbuild?

Tags: functional-testing

I am looking to test model triggers on appbuild, can someone provide steps that could verify successful working for model level triggers

Answer (score 0):

- Login to appbuild testuser/P@ssw0rd
- Use [Mask](https://appbuild.lifion.oneadp.com/api/developer-tools/v1/url/eb8ACQLm8v)
- Go to tile 3a38ae99d3694e12abc3fed555f31fe7
- File to uplload https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1fo7OU8n65BeSju23iMQKnxofnoVSsRuV
- Confirm by looking into kibana for the traceId and see if orchestration logging trigger is fired with no errors